# Formatting DateTime without overriding CultureInfo in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, globalization

In C#, how does one use the DateTime format strings to control what parts of a date are displayed and at the same time not override the CultureInfo?

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfoUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false);
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfoGerman = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE", false);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfoUS;
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("03-13-2012 01:30:00 PM");

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(cultureInfoGerman));
//produces 13.03.2012 13:30:00
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfoGerman));
//produces 03.13.2012 but should be 13.03.2012

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfoGerman;
Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortTimeString());
//produces: 13:30
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("h:mm tt", cultureInfoGerman));
//produces: 1:30 but should be 13:30
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("h:mm tt", cultureInfoUS));
//produces: 1:30 PM
```

You can see the comments in the above code.  The output is partially adjusted by the CultureInfo but not entirely.

Also, the `ToShortDateString` and `ToShortTimeString` methods do not take an `IProvider` and therefore must rely on the current thread's culture info.  This is illustrated with the first example above. Is the expectation that you should change the current culture, call `ToShortDateString` and then revert the thread back to the original culture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the comments in your code - the custom date/time format specifiers you are using behave exactly as I would expect.  Why would you expect "MM/dd/yyyy" to put the day first?

If you want a custom format that is based on the pattern used by a given culture, you can build it by looking at `DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern`, `DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern` etc.  For example, if you wanted a custom format with the day of week followed by a culture-specific short time, you could use:

```
string format = "dddd " + culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(format, culture);
```

> Is the expectation that you should change the current culture, call ToShortDateString and then revert the thread back to the original culture?

No, you should use a [standard date/time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) if you want something other than the current culture:

```
date.ToString("d", culture); // short date
date.ToString("t", culture); // short time
```

Comment: I expect change for the very reason that the "/" is turned into a "." and the DE hour is 1 not 13 and the AM/PM is dropped.  As long as globalization concerns are limited to basic short date and short time, I guess I don't need to worry about it. The answer seems to be that format strings partially override and are partially overridden by the CultureInfo.